# check a text file for 0 or 1 and return based on result?

Tags: c++

I am needing help checking for a string from a text file that is stored on my computer.. pseudo example

```
if String = x {
    Sleep(100)
}
else {
    exit(0)
}
```

I'm just trying to check the text file for a line of text then return a value based on that line... for example if the string is `continue` then I would like it to continue else `exit(0)`.

My C++ project is a dll. Basically what I'm trying to do is open a file that is in the same location as the dll, check it for `0` or `1`, if it returns `1` proceed with the process if it returns `0` terminate it.

Comment: are you just looking for a basic file input example? `std::ifstream in("myfile.txt");` and reading from it?

Comment: You didn't really ask a question. Are you having some problem writing the code you need? If so, what problem are you having?

Comment: @RyanHaining I guess, I am just trying to learn C++ so im not 100% what that means. I'm just trying to check a text file if its containing 0 or 1 and then either continue or exit based on that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yea, I am having a problem writing the code in general because like I said I am trying to learn C++

Comment: @sleep Then you need to learn C++. But if you have a specific problem writing this code, you can ask us a question about it, and we can answer it for you. But you didn't ask any specific question, so what are we supposed to answer? If you want generic help with C++, all you've told us is your objective, which gives us no clue what you need help with. Do you know how to build a DLL? Do you know how to open a file? Do you know what tools to use? How could we possibly know where to start answering?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Could you just give me an example code? I know how to build the DLL.. I dont know how to open the file or read and return based on the value

Comment: @sleep You can find example C++ code anywhere. Just punch "C++ code open file" into your favorite search engine. But it probably won't help you much because it won't be aimed at whatever it is that you are having trouble with. You can't get a *specific* answer without a specific question. (Maybe [start here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) and work some tutorials?)

Comment: Yea, @DavidSchwartz I've been searching around for about 2 hours now.. I am just so stumped.. my objective is to read text from a text file and then do an action based on what it returns.. Could you help me reach this  objective?

Comment: @sleep it's hard to tell what you want here, is it a text file with a single 0 or 1 in it, or is a text file with the text `continue`?

Comment: @RyanHaining It is a text file with a single 0 or 1.. I just need help writing the code on how to search the file for the string and return based on it. I don't need exact code for what I need. I just need an example for what Im looking for..
Ex.
if myfile.contains("0")
{
exit(0)
}
else if myfile.contains ("1")
{
do the code here
}

Comment: @RyanHaining

Right now this is what im doing

https://pastebin.com/raw/wKSqDDv7

however it always returns 0 and terminates even tho the value is 1

Comment: @RyanHaining
okay so looks like the file isn't being opened... I'm calling this in my dll main.. I tried it with just "test.txt" and it being in the same folder as the dll and I tried with "C:\test.txt" both returning file not being opened

Comment: Maybe try with the full path to the file? Why are you doing this with a dll instead of just building an exe?

Comment: @RyanHaining Because im not making an application.. Im doing something that requires me to use a dll.. its game related

Comment: Well, for the purposes of learning you should make a simple standalone exe and then go to a dll when you understand the basics

Comment: @RyanHaining
Thank you, the code you gave me is working how I intended it.. However, I really do need some help implementing this into my project that im working on which is a dll.. its a basic idea for an *antileak* that I plan on making it more complex once I get the base idea down

Comment: You'll need the actual full path to the file you're trying to open then most likely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little back and forth, I believe this is what you want

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  // you probably just want "test.txt" here not "c:\\test.txt"
  std::ifstream data_store("c:\\test.txt");
  if (!data_store.good()) {
    std::cerr << "couldn't open file\n";
    return 1;
  }

  int contents = 0;
  data_store >> contents;

  if (contents == 0) {
    return 0; // or std::exit(0) if not in main
  } else if (contents == 1) {
    // do the rest of the code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan for the solution.. I now have it working how I would like it to do and can now expand from here :)